# Using a loop to print output of arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;

public class AP_ExamArray
{

//User Input AP Exam Scores Using For Loops
public static void main(String args[])
{

   int [] scores = new int[5];

   int j;
   int sum_exam=0;

   for (j=0; j<scores.length; j++)
   {
   Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Please enter AP Exam Score (1-5): ");
   scores[j]=kbReader.nextInt();
   sum_exam+=scores[j];
   }

//Initializer List Final Percentage

double [] final_percent = {97.3, 89.8, 96.2, 70.1, 93.0};

double sum_percent=0;
int k;

for(k=0; k<final_percent.length;k++)
{
sum_percent+=final_percent[k];
}

// String array containing last name (while loop)
String [] last_name = new String[5];
int i=0;
   while (i<last_name.length)
   {
   Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Please enter last name: ");
   last_name[i]=kbReader.next();
   i++;
   }

//Average Exam Scores

double avg_exam = (double) sum_exam/scores.length;

//Average Final Percentage

double avg_percent = (double) sum_percent/final_percent.length;


}
}
```

The directions are:

"For your output use a loop to print the student names, percentages, and test score, and be sure to include appropriate data below each column heading:

Student Name    Student Percentage    Student Test Score."

I'm not sure how to do this!

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Also the problem references a column, is there any special formatting that you need for this?

Comment: I just don't know how to set it up in columns like that and what type of loop to use to do this. I don't think there is any special formatting I need to do that because we haven't learned that.

Comment: Have you learned `System.out.printf()` yet?

Comment: Nope! I don't think my teacher is too concerned with the formatting, more so what loop to use to print out these arrays and how to have a column heading for them .

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
for(i=0; i<scores.length; i++)
    System.out.println(last_names[i] +"\t"+ final_percent[i] +"\t"+ scores[i]);
```

1. A `for` loop is used because you want to loop through the entire
   array of a known size.

   If, instead, you wanted to loop only while a certain condition holds
   you would use a  `while` loop: (e.g. `while(condition) loop;`).
2. `System.out.println()` will print a new line after each call, and `\t` will add a tab.

---

For  better formatting check out [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) Oracle doc on using `printf` and `format`